# why is this xss not working

Tags: javascript, php, security, xss

I am just trying to exercise on xss and I want the alert box to pop up on echo which should work on echo. I am doing exercises based on concepts and hier I have a wrong usage of htmlspecialchars, which is vulnerable to xss. However this is not really working and I don't get why. here is my code

```
$name=htmlspecialchars($_GET['myname']);


echo "<HTML><body>";        
echo '<form action="">';
echo "name: <input type='text' name='myname' ><br>";

echo "<input type='submit' ></form>";

echo $name; // here I want the xss to execute a popup box

echo "</HTML></body>";
```

The input script looks like this.

```
<script>alert();</script>
```

I have also tried many alternatives. The script is displayed as I typed it and there is not alert box.

Comment: ask it on https://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You are supposed to close the body tag before html. also add method to your form

Comment: @Akin Not necessary to close some tags in HTML5, and GET is assumed if no method given.

Comment: Surely the `<html>` tag should be before the `<script>`. Ideally, the `<script>` would be within a `<head>` tag.

Comment: Why is this a wrong usage of the `htmlspecialchars()` function?

Comment: look at this if it could help <https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Top_5#How_to_Determine_if_you_are_Vulnerable_2 >

Comment: @SteveLovell I did put the script after html and the result was the same. no XSS

Comment: @Thoby The best way would be for instance with ENT_QUOTES, and encoding  'UTF-8' .htmlspecialchars($_GET['myname'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

Comment: @eskoba I did have a look at it already. However it does not say much on why. and looking at I think I followed the concept

Answer (score 3):

> I am doing exercises based on concepts and hier I have a wrong usage of htmlspecialchars, which is vulnerable to xss.

You don't, though. You've used `htmlspecialchars` exactly as it's supposed to be used, and are thus protected against XSS here.

Comment: not really. The ENT_QUOTES is not set. the correct way should be htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

Comment: @zeroday `ENT_QUOTES` is irrelevant here (it simply affects how `'` and `"` get escaped). The `<` and `>` characters are still being escaped, preventing the `<script>` tag from working at all. No need to specify UTF-8, either, as it's the default in all supported versions of PHP.

Comment: Here is are some supposedly working injections https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/145716/xss-bypass-strtoupper-htmlspecialchars  and this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EjiCSWKlsWI

Comment: @zeroday They work because of the specifics of the vulnerable code. Look at the examples, and look at what `ENT_QUOTES` does. You should quickly understand why the examples in those links are vulnerable, and why **your code is not**. Your code doesn't break when single-quotes aren't escaped, so it's not vulnerable. Specifying `ENT_QUOTES` (or just using `htmlentities`) is a best practice because **sometimes** you will write code with `'` that becomes vulnerable.

Answer (score 2):

> I have a wrong usage of htmlspecialchars, which is vulnerable to xss

Your usage isn't wrong for the rest of the code you have, and it isn't vulnerable to XSS for the code that you have.

Using `htmlspecialchars` with only one argument uses the default settings which makes `<`, `"`, `>`, and `&` characters safe.

This is absolutely fine when the content is being output somewhere that you could put a text node.

The main situation where it isn't enough to protect your HTML is when you are:

- Delimiting your attribute values with `'` instead of `"`
- Putting the data inside an attribute value

That's when you need `ENT_QUOTES` so that `'` gets escaped to. Otherwise you could end up with:

```
$user_input = "' onmouseover='alert(1)'";
?>
<body data-userinput='<?php echo $user_input; ?>'>
```

… so new attributes which trigger JS could be added.

(Note you also need different sanitisation techniques if you are inserting data into JS or URLs).

Comment: how could then explain these working injections https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/145716/xss-bypass-strtoupper-htmlspecialchars  and this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EjiCSWKlsWI

Comment: @zeroday — "how could then explain these working injections" — I explained that one **in the answer** I just gave! It puts the value in a single quote delimited attribute just as I demonstrated! (And I'm not going to go and watch a video, I don't have time for that).